# Spring integration how can I move a file after FTP'ing it?

Tags: spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration to FTP a file. After I've processed that file though I'd like to move the file from the FTP directory, to an archive directory on the FTP server. How can I do this?

I had figured the solution might involve enriching the method header with the filename, but it doesn't look like the streaming channel adapter makes that available (since it's just a stream and not a File/Path).

```
<int-ftp:inbound-streaming-channel-adapter
    auto-startup="true" id="ftpListener2" channel="ftpChannel"
    session-factory="ftpSessionFactory" remote-directory="/data/crp/prd/ald/01/stuff/archive"
    filename-pattern="ADX_I.2017083100100.tar.gz">
    <integration:poller fixed-rate="5000"
        max-messages-per-poll="-1" />
</int-ftp:inbound-streaming-channel-adapter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message returned from the Streaming Channel Adapter is like this:

```
 return getMessageBuilderFactory()
                    .withPayload(session.readRaw(remotePath))
                    .setHeader(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.CLOSEABLE_RESOURCE, session)
                    .setHeader(FileHeaders.REMOTE_DIRECTORY, file.getRemoteDirectory())
                    .setHeader(FileHeaders.REMOTE_FILE, file.getFilename())
                    .setHeader(FileHeaders.REMOTE_FILE_INFO,
                            this.fileInfoJson ? file.toJson() : file)
                    .build();
```

So, you have all the info related to the remote file.

So, you definitely can use `<int-ftp:outbound-gateway>` to perform `MV` command with that info in the headers of the request message.

Comment: Would you say that the java approach is easier for this than xml? So far, everything I've done is in xml, but I'm open to defining beans in java.

Comment: Yep! That can be done! See Java DSL approach: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference

Comment: I see the Java DSL equivalent of my FTP code (returning a IntegrationFlow ). I am still a bit confused though as to where your code fits in with this. The example returns an IntegrationFlow but this returns a MessageBuilderFactory

Comment: ??? I show you the code from the Framework: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-file/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/file/remote/AbstractRemoteFileStreamingMessageSource.java#L158. As a confirmation that you really have all the info in the downstream message. I don't show you the target solution. That is already out of StackOverflow scope. Nobody here is going to write code for you.

Comment: I think I understand now. Thank you for the examples.